# How can I understand Android crash errors and rectify them

Tags: android, debugging, stack-trace, google-play

This is an example of one of the stack traces, how do I fix my application from this?  are there any other tools in google marketplace that help me with this?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL:
>   content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1 at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1255) at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
>   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:450)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:587) at
>   com.multi.board.series9button.function2(series9button.java:155) at
>   com.multi.board.series9button.onContextItemSelected(series9button.java:95)
>   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2206) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2781)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:876)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382) at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

---

EDIT:

I actually called it function 2!  what poor programming that is.  Here is the function.  The problem is I couldn't get this to crash on my phone or any other I tried....

> ```
> public void function2(int id){
>       Toast.makeText(this, "Set as notification",
> ```
>
> Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             String sdcard =
>   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
>
> ```
>             String path = sdcard + "/multi10/" + Global.currentboard +
> ```
>
> "/series9";
>
> ```
>                   File k = new File(path, Global.currentsound);
>
>                   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>                   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
> ```
>
> k.getAbsolutePath());
>                         values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
>   "MultiboardNotif");
>                         values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
>   "audio/mpeg");
>                         values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Unknown
>   artist");
>                         values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,
>   false);
>                         values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION,
>   true);
>                         values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
>                         values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
>
> ```
>                   Uri uri =
> ```
>
> MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
>
> getContentResolver().delete(uri,MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE + "=\""
>   + "MultiboardNotif" +"\"", null);
>                     Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
>
> ```
>                   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
>                     series9button.this,
>                     RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
>                     newUri);
>
>   }
> ```

---

**RESOLVED**

Well I now understand how the crash errors work now!  and this is how I resolved my issue:

I had a problem on some phones when setting the ringtone as a sound from the directory I store my sounds in on the sdcard.

I add a file to tell the media scanner not to scan the files in my directories and add them to the database.

So to get round this when the set as ringtone/notification/alarm button is pressed I copy the file to a directory on the sdcard called `\<sdard>\ringtones` or `\<sdard>\notifications` or `\<sdard>\alarms` and the code I used previously works fine from that location.

Comment: please add some code, specifically 'function2'.

Comment: but there is all what you need ... series9button.java line 155 ... you're trying to insert album with Uri content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1 ...

Comment: @Selvin ofcourse, but since the guy doesnt know what a stacktrace is :>

Comment: i can say even more ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308409/changing-the-text-message-notification-not-the-everything-else-notification this cousing an error ... sometimes i think that programming is not for every one ...

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/add-ringtone-on-android-2-1-t52383.html same symptoms ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Android crash error" you are referring to is actually a JAVA stack trace. Googling for that is sure to bring up a lot of results. Let me give you a few pointers though:

- such a stack trace is dumped to the error stream when an exception is thrown that is not caught.
- The first line contains the class name of the exception (in your case `java.lang.IllegalStateException`) followed by the message of the exception ("Unknown URL: content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1"). This tells you WHAT happened.
- The rest of the stack trace contains info on WHERE it happened. Since functions call each other, you will see several functions in the reverse order that they were called, one per line. In your example:

  - exception occurred in class `android.os.Parcel` method `readException()` in file `Parcel.java` at line `1255`
  - that method was called by `android.database.DatabaseUtils` method `readExceptionFromParcel()` in file `DatabaseUtils.java` at line `160`
  - ......

You will most likely be interested in the LATEST (topmost) method call that comes FROM YOUR CODE, since in 99% of the times is what causes the error. in your case, that's `com.multi.board.series9button.function2(series9button.java:155)` (you interpret that as `function2()` from the class `com.multi.board.series9button` line `155`).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  The problem is when someone tried to set a sound as a ringtone...  My problem is I can't reproduce it, is there any way to tell what version of android it's from or what device is causing the error?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to determine the android version or device from the stack trace... didn't the crash log contain any other info?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse or Netbeans, you can use the built-in debugger.  Personally, my method (since that debugger can be not helpful sometimes) is to put "Log.d("FileName","Message about location");" throughout my code.  Then follow along with the program in the code and when you get that error, you will know exactly where it is.  And then comes the fun of solving it...

Comment: Upvoted because logging is useful if you're looking for an error and can't figure it out.